# h:selectOneRadio button is retaining previous value

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

Okay the problem is with the radio button in JSF 1.2. I have two sets of radio button, the trigger of first populates the second radio button set. On the trigger of the first radio button set, it's calling the backend method, definitely it's through ValueChangeListener. The code snippet is :

```xhtml
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{ApplicantRegistration.appliedForAward}" 
style="font-size:1.5em;" id="award" onclick="this.form.submit();"
valueChangeListener="#{ApplicantRegistration.checkWhetherAppliedForAward}" immediate="true">

    <f:selectItem itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="No" itemLabel="No" />  

</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Second radio button set

```xhtml
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{ApplicantRegistration.appliedForInvitation}" 
style="font-size:1.5em;" id="invitation" onclick="this.form.submit();" 
valueChangeListener="#{ApplicantRegistration.checkWhetherAppliedForInvitation}" immediate="true">

    <f:selectItem itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="No" itemLabel="No" />

</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Now, when I select Yes in first radio button set, the second radio button set renders. Initially, the none of the option are checked in second radio button set. Now from the second radio button set, I select any Yes/No. Again now from the first radio button set when I select the No, the second radio button set renders with the same value which I selected during the Yes case of the first radio button. On change of the first radio button, I am clearing the value of the second radio button set in the backend.
The backend code looks like :

```java
public void checkWhetherAppliedForAward(ValueChangeEvent evt) {
    appliedForInvitation = "";
}
```

The bean is in SessionScope. Both the variable are String type.

Comment: Check the getter method for `appliedForInvitation`. Is it behaving as expected?

Comment: Are you sure your change listener is evn being called? because you're submitting the form 'onclick' this is likely happening strait away before the valueChangeListner has a change to update the value. :)

Comment: @XtremeBiker yes the getter method is behaving as expected.4

Comment: @VeenarM yes it's printing the value whenever a radio button change is occurred.